# How can I add text right next to (to the right of) an ellipsis text overflow in CSS?

Tags: css, text, overflow

I am trying to use ellipsis text overflow but it is messing up my layout. I have the following code:

`.complete{
    max-width: 300px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    margin-right:10px;
}`

So an example of what this does is:

This is a group... 
                      New York

Where 'This is a group' is the truncated text and New York is the text that I want right next to 'This is a group...'. So it should look like this:

This is a group...   New York

'New York' was being displayed in the right place before doing the text overflow, although 'This is a group' was overlapping it.

Any ideas? Thanks in advnace!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/6d9gL/

You can contain the text in `inline-block` elements and have them annexed, as in a normal text line.

Also please note the use of `vertical-align:middle;` it is needed to keep the elements aligned in one line. (Try removing the property and see the effect)

CSS

```
.complete {
    display:inline-block;
    max-width: 120px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.annexed {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

HTML

```
<span class="complete">This is a group to test the ellipsis</span>
<span class="annexed">New York</span>
```

Comment: I was missing the 'vertical-align:middle;". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use two elements:

```
<div>
    Stuff stuff woohoo I'm typing stuff
</div>
<div>
    Yay
</div>

*
{
    font-size: 0;
}

div
{
    display: inline-block;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;

    font-size: 16px;
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5mKQ9/)

Comment: I was missing the "vertical-align:middle". Thanks!